# Is there a way to use GLSL programs as filters?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Assume that we have different shader programs for different objects in a game. For example the player model has a shader that controls skeleton system (bone matrices multiplication etc.), or a particle has a shader for sparkling effects, wall has parallax mapping etc.

But what if I want to add fog to the game that must affect every one of these objects ? For example I have a room that will have a red fog, should I change EVERY glsl program to have fog code or is there a possible way to make global filters ? Should I change every glsl program when i want to add a feature ?

Comment: I'm new to glsl/open gl but... Shouldn't you use a fragment shader in post process and play with the depth buffer ? I'm nearly sure about the fact you don't need to mod any of your existing shader.

Comment: But can i use different fragment programs at the same time ?

Comment: Yeah, and the first time I did it was... Next week ^^ I think, you can draw an invisible, full screen quad, on which you apply the post process shaders. (Again, I haven't tested it myself yet)

Comment: i liked this idea actually, you mean framebuffer objects, render to texture and process it ?

Comment: More detailed answers about multiple render passes [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22216/using-multiple-shaders)

Comment: I'll let the pro speak, I don't know how to do it. Gerald answer seems nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical process for this type of thing is to use a full-screen shader in post processing using the depth buffer from your fully rendered scene, or using a z-pass, which renders only to the depth buffer. You can chain them together and create any number of effects. It typically involves some render-to-texture work, and is not a real trivial task (too much to post code here), but it's not THAT difficult either.

If you want to take a look at a decent post-processing system, take a look at the PostFx system in Torque3D:

https://github.com/GarageGames/Torque3D

And here is an example of creating fog with GLSL in post:

http://isnippets.blogspot.com/2010/10/real-time-fog-using-post-processing-in.html

Comment: Thanks for the post processing answer

Comment: Just want to point out, that the render to texture approach means another shader pass which can have performance / power implecations

Comment: Of course, any time you add more work to your render pipeline there will be potential performance implications. But when you get into advanced rendering scenarios with multiple post-processing filters, it's difficult to avoid. Sometimes it will even have performance benefits; i.e. an additional pass into a smaller texture for certain post-processing effects that would eat your performance for lunch if done full-screen from the backbuffer. It all depends on what you're doing.